# fast way to find text files not ending with a specified string

Tags: linux, bash, text, text-processing

I have many many xml files and want to check their completeness by verifying if they end with `</root>` tag.

`grep -L "</root>" *.xml`

does the tricky but rather slow (too many and large files). Is there a quicker solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large files, if you sure that the target string is at the end of them, use `tail`:

```
tail -n 10 filename.xml | grep "</root>" # will check the last 10 lines for the pattern
```

Tested on text file ~ 7GB, single `grep` ~ 20s, with `tail` less then 0.01s

For the number of files (and print file names whicn NOT contains the pattern):

```
for f in *.xml ; do tail -n 10 "$f" | grep -q "</root>" || echo "$f" ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks a good way. But I got a lot of `(standard input)` output to screen. I used `grep -L` in the Q to output the filenames that not end with `</root>`.

Comment: @Lee Answer updated (if I understand your requirements correctly)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should probably use `"</root>$"` to ensure the file actually *ends* with the tag, rather than simply having `</root>` *somewhere* on the last line.

Comment: @chepner Surely, but strictly speaking :) Q was about speed, not about checking for pattern. I just don't know, probably, it could be something like `</root></body>`, so it is up to OP.